# How would Azure Data Factory work in this scenario?

Tags: azure, github, azure-data-factory, devops

hoping someone can help expand my knowledge on Azure Data Factory with what would happen in this scenario. Unfortunately I can't trial-and-error it, so some tips would be appreciated.

I have three environments: dev, test and prod.

In Dev, I have pipeline1, pipeline2, dataset1. Dev is the only environment connected to github

In Test, I have pipeline1, pipeline2, dataset1.

In Prod, I have pipeline1, pipeline2, pipeline3, dataset1.

In dev, I delete pipeline2 as its not needed. Then using a devops pipeline I promote the changes from dev through the other environments. My question is, what happens to pipeline3 in production. It didn't exist in previous environments, and is not impacted by the change of deleting pipeline2.

Will it:

Remain in prod, untouched by the changes.

Be deleted, as its not in dev when the changes are promoted through the environments?

Both seem logical to me, but I am not sure which one will happen and unfortunately can't risk just trying it to see. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Typically it will delete the existing pipeline 3 in production unless configured otherwise, I would advise getting the Json code of the data factory pipeline 3 and saving that before applying or promoting changes so that you have the code at hand.

Once you have the code save it to a vs code document as a Json file or just use notepad ++ to save the pipeline to local storage before committing any changes

[image: Getting Json code for pipeline 3]